# Mongoose populate return empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose and I'm facing an issue when I try to populate a subdocument.

I have designed 3 models in Mongoose : Account, Contact and Group.
Account owns both multiple contacts and groups. Group owns some contacts.

Here are my models :

### Account.ts

```js
import Mongoose from "../services/Mongoose";
import {ContactSchema, IContact} from "./Contact";
import {GroupSchema, IGroup} from "./Group";

export interface IAccount extends Mongoose.Document {
  contacts: Mongoose.Types.DocumentArray<IContact>
  groups: Mongoose.Types.DocumentArray<IGroup>
}

export const AccountSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  contacts: [ContactSchema],
  groups: [GroupSchema],
});

const Account = Mongoose.model<IAccount>('Account', AccountSchema);
export default Account;
```

### Contact.ts

```js
import Mongoose from "../services/Mongoose";

export interface IContact extends Mongoose.Document {
  lastName: string
  firstName: string
}

export const ContactSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  lastName: {type: String, default: ""},
  firstName: {type: String, default: ""},
});

const Contact = Mongoose.model<IContact>('Contact', ContactSchema);
export default Contact;
```

### Group.ts

```js
import Mongoose from "../services/Mongoose";
import {IContact} from "./Contact";
import {Schema} from "mongoose";

export interface IGroup extends Mongoose.Document {
  name: string
  comments: string
  contacts: IContact["_id"][]
}

export const GroupSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  comments: {type: String, default: ""},
  contacts: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Contact"}]
});

const Group = Mongoose.model<IGroup>('Group', GroupSchema);
export default Group;
```

## My populate issue

The issue occurs when I want to populate Account.Groups.Contacts.

```js
//With this query, I can see all the contacts' ObjectId in the groups.contacts property.
const account = await Account.findById(res.locals.accountId);

//However, with this one, contacts property in groups is an empty array.
const account = await Account.findById(res.locals.accountId).populate("groups.contacts").exec();
```

How can I populate path groups.contacts of my account properly?

Thank in advance for your contribution.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?